# problema con input radio

Tags: javascript, radiobutton

buenos dias.

El detalle es que tengo dos `inputs` radio, el cual al dar click a uno de ellos quiero que me muestre un `div` que esta oculto al abrir la pagina, e intentado varios métodos y ninguno funciona, esto lo quiero hacer en `javascript`, he intentado con:

```
$("input[type=radio]").on("change",function()

$('input:radio[name=bedStatus]:checked').change(function () {})
```

y aun no encuentro solución, quiero acceder al evento `change` del radio

Comment: `$('input[name=bedStatus]').on('change', function() { ... });` ese es el código básico para el input con ese nombre. Como no tenemos el resto del código, poco más podemos hacer...

Comment: Podrías incluír tu html para poder hacer pruebas por favor

Comment: <input type="radio" name="bedStatus" data-radio="iradio_minimal-blue" id="Fechas" value="1">

Answer (score 6):

Básicamente, para saber si un radio esta checkeado o no debes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
$("input[name=bedStatus]").click(function() {  
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {  
       $("#contenido").fadeIn();
    } 
 });
```

```css
#contenido{
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="bedStatus" id="bedStatus">
<label for="bedStatus">Mostrar contenido</label>

<div id="contenido">Soy el contenido</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Intenta asignandole el mismo nombre al radio para que siempre haya un solo seleccionado. Luego se le de clic al radio muestras el div o lo ocultalas utilizando `addClass()` y `removeClass()`:

```js
$("#ocultar2").change(function(){
  $("#div1").addClass('oculto');
});

$("#ocultar1").change(function(){
  $("#div1").removeClass('oculto');
});
```

```css
.oculto{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="nombreInput" id="ocultar1" /> Mostrar  
  
  <input type="radio"  name="nombreInput" id="ocultar2" /> Ocultar 
</div>

<div class="oculto" id="div1">
Div 1
</div>
```

Comment: El posteador pide la solución con un `radiobutton` y no un `checkbox` no podemos saber si cambiar el input afecte al resto de su aplicación

Answer (score 3):

Deberías utilizar el evento click:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#ocultar').click(function(){
    $('#ocultar-mostrar').addClass('oculto');
  });
  $('#mostrar').click(function(){
    $('#ocultar-mostrar').removeClass('oculto');
  });

});
```

```css
div{
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.oculto{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="bedStatus" id="mostrar" value="mostrar">
<label for="mostrar">Mostrar</label>
<input type="radio" name="bedStatus" id="ocultar" value="ocultar" checked>
<label for="ocultar">Ocultar</label>


<div id="ocultar-mostrar" class="oculto">
  Div oculto
</div>
```